# ¿Cómo puedo crear un objeto dentro de otro objeto?

Tags: java, android-studio

hace dos meses que estoy aprendiendo programación Android y me gustaría saber cómo crear un objeto dentro de otro objeto. Mi intención es poder crear algo parecido a esto:

[image: Captura de la sección de restaurantes de la app McDonald's]

Quiero inflar un RecyclerView con los datos de los "Restaurantes" (no tengo ningún problema con esto) y dentro de cada elemento "Restaurante" quiero que contenga otra lista de los datos "servicios".

Gracias.

Comment: La duda que tenés es sobre el layout de dentro de cada item del RecyclerView? Los servicios son los iconos que están abajo horizontal? Desde acá parecen botones o imagenes. Cuás sería la duda concreta?

Comment: Efectivamente los servicios son los iconos que están situados en horizontal. No son botones. No tengo dudas con el Layout.

Comment: No queda clara cual es la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que tenes los conceptos confundidos, o no te estas explicando bien. No tenes que crear "objetos dentro de otros". En este caso deberias crear 2 clases: Restaurantes y Servicios y relacionarlas.

Comment: Perdonad si no me explico bien, es que al ser nuevo no sé el "lenguaje técnico". Efectivamente ZottoSL, me estaba refiriendo a crear dos clases con sus respectivos constructores, getters y setters. Lo que no sé es como relacionarlas. Lo que necesito es que los datos de la clase "servicios" estén incluidos en la clase Restaurantes como un campo más. Espero que se entienda mejor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo que no sé es como relacionarlas. Lo que necesito es que los datos
>   de la clase "servicios" estén incluidos en la clase Restaurantes como
>   un campo más.

Si tenmos la clase `Restaurant` y la la clase `Servicio`, y establecemos que un `Restaurant` presta varios `Servicios`, la forma de modelar la clase `Restaurant` sería:

```
public class Restaurant{
    ... // Otros atributos como nombre, dirección, etc.
    List<Servicio> servicios = new ArrayList<Servicio>();

    public void addServicio(Servicio servicio){
        this.servicios.add(servicio);
    }

    // También se puede definir un getter y setter para obtener o setear directamente el List<Servicio>, en lugar de usar el metodo `add` para agregarlos de a uno.
}
```

En este caso utilicé una lista y agregamos un método para poder agregar los servicios a la misma.

Usé una lista pensando en que no son una gran cantidad de servicios y cuando necesite trabajar con ellos lo puedo hacer recorriendo la lista.

Hay otros tipos de colecciones en el paquete `java.util` que podes explorar como Map que permite un acceso más directo siempre que cuentes con un identificador, en este caso, del servicio. (Que podría ser...).